# Retrieve image from storage Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to retrieve text intervention image from the storage to my blade view, I have created a storage link.

```php
//Here is my controller

$post = Image::make(
       $request->file('content')->getRealPath())->save('public/content'.$fileNameToStore);
       $post->resize(300, 300);
       $post->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 10, 10);
       $post->save();

//Here is my blade view

<img src="{{ asset('storage/content/'.$post->content) }}">
```

How can I retrieve an image from `public/storage/content` into blade or save first into database and then retrieve them into blade view.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it throwing an error? or is the image just not showing up? did you echo asset('storage/content/'.$post->content) to see if the path is correct?

Comment: It looks like you are saving to `public/content` but trying to retrieve from `storage/content`

Comment: There is no throwing error and image not showing up

Comment: May one show me how to retrieve because I am new in laravel

Answer (score 0):

please try this for Retrieve image from storage Laravel

```html
@php $picture = url('storage/content/'.$post->content); @endphp
<img src="{{ $picture }}" class="pic_preview" width="auto" height="100px">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your code, you're trying to save the file to the directory `public/content` which means your file will be saved into `your_project/public/public/content folder`. You don't need to pass `public` just pass `content/filename.ext` and to retrieve call the same `content/filename.ext`. Make sure your folder `content` under `your_project/public/content` exists and is having writable permission (0777).

Corrected code:

```
//Here is my controller

$post = Image::make(
       $request->file('content')->getRealPath())->save('content/'.$fileNameToStore);
       $post->resize(300, 300);
       $post->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 10, 10);
       $post->save();

//Here is my blade view

<img src="{{ asset('content/'.$post->content) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

this how i will do it

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
        
        $file      = $request->file;
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename  = 'iddocument-'.time() .rand().'.'.$extension;
        $path      = $file->storeAs('iddocuments', $filename);
        
        $user = auth()->user();
        $userimag= new userimag();
        $userimag->user_id = $userimag->id;
        $userimag->doc_url = $path;
        if($userimag->save()){
            
            $path = storage_path().'/app/'.$path;
            if (!File::exists($path)) {
              abort(402);
            }
            
            $file = File::get($path);
            $type = File::mimeType($path);
            $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));
            
            return Response(['error_code'=>200,
            'pic'=>$image,'format'=>$type,'picname'=>$filename,'id'=>$kyc->id,'created_at'=>\Carbon\Carbon::parse($kyc->created_at)->format('dS M Y H:i:s')],200);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your suggestion.